# Estrutura de Dados, Lista Duplamente Encadeada. Dúvida sobre o Construtor da classe ListaDupla

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

> Obs.: Código retirado de uma apostila de Estrutura de Dados.
>
> Por que não passar a quantidade de nós da Lista Duplamente Encadeada pelo Construtor dela (como nas estruturas de Pilha ou Fila)?

```
public class ListaDupla {
    private NoDupla prim;
    private NoDupla ult;
    private int quantNos;

    public ListaDupla(){
        this.prim = null;
        this.ult = null;
        this.quantNos = 0;
    }
    public int getQuantNos(){
        return this.quantNos;
    }
    public NoDupla getPrim(){
        return this.prim;
    }
    public NoDupla getUlt(){
        return this.ult;
    }
    public void setQuantNos(int valorNovo){
        this.quantNos = valorNovo;
    }
    public void setPrim(NoDupla novoNo){
        this.prim = novoNo;
    }
    public void setUlt(NoDupla novoNo){
        this.ult = novoNo;
    }
    public boolean eVazia (){
        return (this.prim == null);
    }
    public void inserirPrimeiro(Item elem){
        NoDupla novoNo = new NoDupla (elem);
        if (this.eVazia())
            this.ult = novoNo;
        else { 
            novoNo.setProx(this.prim);
            this.prim.setAnt(novoNo);
        }
        this.prim = novoNo;
        this.quantNos++;
    }
    public void inserirUltimo (Item elem){
        NoDupla novoNo = new NoDupla (elem);
        if (this.eVazia())
            this.prim = novoNo;
        else { 
            novoNo.setAnt(this.ult);
            this.ult.setProx(novoNo);
        }    
        this.ult = novoNo;
        this.quantNos++;
    }
    public NoDupla pesquisarNo (int chave){
        NoDupla atual = this.prim;
        while ((atual != null) && (atual.getInfo().getChave() != chave))
            atual = atual.getProx();
        return atual;
    }
    public boolean removerNo (int chave){
        NoDupla atual = this.prim;
        while ((atual != null) && (atual.getInfo().getChave()!= chave)){
            atual = atual.getProx();
        }
        if (atual == null)
            return false;
        else 
            if (atual == this.prim){
                this.prim = prim.getProx();
                if (this.prim == null)
                    this.ult=null;
                else 
                    this.prim.setAnt(null);
            }
            else 
                if (atual == this.ult){
                    this.ult = this.ult.getAnt();
                    this.ult.setProx(null);
                }
                else {
                    atual.getProx().setAnt(atual.getAnt());
                    atual.getAnt().setProx(atual.getProx());
                }
        this.quantNos--;
        return true;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String msg="";
        NoDupla atual = this.prim;
        while (atual != null){
            msg += atual.getInfo().getChave()+"\n";
            atual = atual.getProx();
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente foi feito assim porque a intenção é que você só possa criar uma lista vazia (sem nenhum nó).

A lista sempre começa vazia, e conforme você for adicionando e removendo elementos, a quantidade de nós vai sendo atualizada. Repare que somente os métodos que inserem ou removem elementos atualizam o valor da quantidade (seja incrementando com `++` ou decrementando com `--`). O único problema, na minha opinião, é o método `setQuantNos`, mas vamos deixá-lo pro final.

Vamos supor que você crie um construtor que recebe a quantidade de nós como parâmetro:

```
public ListaDupla(int quantidade){
    this.prim = null;
    this.ult = null;
    this.quantNos = quantidade;
}
```

Depois você cria uma lista com 100 elementos:

```
ListaDupla lista = new ListaDupla(100);
```

O tamanho da lista é 100, mas quais são os 100 elementos dela? Eu ainda não inseri nenhum. O tamanho indica 100, mas na verdade não tem nenhum (`prim` e `ult` estão nulos), o que torna o estado da lista inconsistente, pois o valor de `quantNos` indica que tem mais elementos do que fato existem.

Se eu inserir 1 elemento, a quantidade vai ser incrementada e passa a ser 101. Mas eu só inseri 1 elemento, então a lista vai continuar inconsistente. O modo como a lista foi implementada só funciona se ela sempre começar com quantidade zero.

---

Eu só acho que o método `setQuantNos` não faz muito sentido ali, pois quem controla a quantidade de nós são os métodos que inserem ou removem um elemento.

Se eu posso setar o tamanho da lista diretamente, sem inserir nem remover nenhum elemento, isso deixa o estado interno da lista inconsistente. Por exemplo, se eu crio uma lista, não adiciono nenhum elemento e chamo `setQuantNos(100)`, ela vai achar que tem 100 elementos, mesmo eu não tendo inserido nenhum (o mesmo problema de ter um construtor que recebe a quantidade).